# facebook share buttuon image not working properly

Tags: facebook

i don't know english very well and sorry about this. then i try to explan my problem
i want to add facebook share attribute to my site. code below

head tag

```
 <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

body tag

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">
<img src="img/pFace.png" alt="Share on Facebook" /></a>
```

then test my code link doesnt work but when delete img tag share work properly.

where is the mistake?

I discover that actually issue is facebook share link is not loaded or delay.
In your view what is possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The share button is depreceated. It's preferable to use the 'like' button. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: but i don't have a fan page. I want to post a text to user's profile. How can i do this?